# Logic order to append values in a list (python)

Tags: python, list, append

I noticed an error in the logic order of my code when trying to append a value into a list, my code works anyway. The two examples below illustrate the problem. Can someone tell me what it's going on in the first example?

```
# example 1    
text_1 = []    
a_1 = []    
text_1.append(a_1)    
a_1.append('BBB') # this command should be before the last one    
print('text 1: ',text_1) # prints [['BBB']]
# example 2    
text_2 = []    
a_2 = []    
text_2.append(a_2)    
a_2 = ['BBB'] # this command should be before the last one    
print('text 2: ',text_2) # prints [[]]
```

Comment: `a_2 = ['BBB']` is creating a new list object whereas, in `a_1.append('BBB')`, you append to same list object.

Comment: What is a "logy order"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer here is that the variables refer to memory addresses. In the first example, you change *the data at that memory address*. In the second example, you change *the memory address the variable refers to*. I've commented your examples to make the difference more clear:

Example 1:

```
text_1 = []    
a_1 = []            # a_1 refers to a pointer somewhere in memory
                    # Let's call it LOC_A
                    # The data at LOC_A is [].
text_1.append(a_1)  # appends whatever data is at a_1 as the last element
                    # a_1 == LOC_A -> []
                    # text_1 == [LOC_A] == [[]]
a_1.append('BBB')   # LOC_A -> ['BBB']
                    # text_1 == [LOC_A] == [['BBB']]   
print('text 1: ',text_1)  # prints [['BBB']]
```

Example 2:

```
text_2 = []    
a_2 = []            # a_2 refers to a pointer somewhere in memory
                    # let's call this location LOC_A
text_2.append(a_2)  # appends whatever data is at LOC_A as the last element
                    # a_2 == LOC_A -> []
                    # text_1 == [LOC_A] == [[]]
a_2 = ['BBB']       # a_2 now refers to a  different pointer, LOC_B
                    # a_2 == LOC_B -> ['BBB']
                    # LOC_A has not changed, is still [], and text_1 still refers to it
                    # text_1 == [LOC_A] == [[]]  
print('text 2: ',text_2)  # prints [[]]
```

Comment: Using memory addresses is a poor analogy in Python. Python doesn't quite work that way, as C maybe does. Python uses *names*, see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.